# CRON job not running without recent (<24 hours) login--beyond basic troubleshooting

Tags: python, bash, cron

### Background:

I wrote a bash script that queries a list of storage blocks, calls Python3 to analyze the result of the query, then mounts a drive. I want to run the script just before I run rsnapshot every morning, so I scheduled the script in a crontab in /etc/cron.d/.

### Symptoms:

- I have tested just the bash script with "sudo bash checkmount.bash" and it runs without error.
- I have scheduled the bash script to run using a cron tab in /etc/cron.d/ while I am logged in, and it completes.
- I have scheduled the bash script to run using same cron tab in /etc/cron.d/ while I am logged out, and it completes.
- I have scheduled the bash script to run using same cron tab in /etc/cron.d/ while I am logged out, but **when I check 2-3 days later, it has not run at all.**

### Troubleshooting:

- I made sure the bash script and python3 scripts are in /usr/local/bin/, which is accessible to root (the user that runs the script). The scripts are owned and rwx-permissions by root.
- I checked "grep CRON /var/log/syslog" and "grep cron /var/log/syslog/". While I am logged out for 2-3 days, the cron does not even appear in syslog. If the cron runs while I am logged in, the CRON appears in the log and reports no errors.
- I made sure that the files referenced in the bash script where full paths + filenames. The paths + filenames are all accessible to root user, who runs the script.
- I directed stdout and stderr to a file I could review later. If I am logged in when the CRON runs, it has only output that I wrote into the script, no errors. If I am logged out when CRON is supposed to run, there is no output to the file.

### Files:

- bash script is in /usr/local/bin/. The permissions on the file are: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root
  Bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#list the devices in /dev in .mount1.txt
#Process the list, save devices that do not hold the LVM and are large enough to backup the LVM

lsblk --output=NAME,SIZE,TYPE --bytes > /usr/local/bin/.mount1.txt
python3 /usr/local/bin/validDisks.py /usr/local/bin/.mount1.txt /usr/local/bin/.mount2.txt

#Empty .mount3.txt
> /usr/local/bin/.mount3.txt

#Open .mount2.txt and for each line
# run lsblk and append output to .mount3.txt
input1=/usr/local/bin/.mount2.txt
while read line1
do
    echo $(lsblk $line1 --output=MOUNTPOINT -n) >> /usr/local/bin/.mount3.txt
    operand=$(< /usr/local/bin/.mount3.txt)
    if [[ -n $operand ]]
    then
        echo $line1 "is mounted at " $operand "."
    else
        echo $line1 "is not mounted."
        mount $line1 /mnt/externaldrive
        if [[ $? ]]
        then
            echo "mounted " $line1
        else
            echo "failed to mount"
        fi
    fi
done < $input1
lsblk
```

- python3 script is in /usr/local/bin. The permissions on the file are:-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root
  Python3 script:

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import io
import re

###Method Definitions###

def makeRawFrame(filename):
    rawtargetframe = []
    print(".")
#Open the text data
    openfile = open(filename)
    print("..")
#Convert each row in the text data into a list of items delimited by whitespace
    for i in openfile:
        framerow=re.split("\s", i)
        print("...")
        rawtargetframe.append(framerow)
        print("....")
    openfile.close()
    print(".....")
    return rawtargetframe

def makeTrimFrame(frame):
#make the empty frame
    trimmedFrame = []
    print('.')
#iterate each row in the raw frame
    for i in frame: 
#make an empty row to add to the new frame
        trimmedRow = []
        print("..")
#iterate each item in the raw row
        for j in i: 
            print("...")
#if the item is non-empty, append to new row
            if j != '':
                trimmedRow.append(trimNonAN(j))
#when row is done reading, append to new frame
        trimmedFrame.append(trimmedRow)
    print("....")
    return trimmedFrame

def trimNonAN(str):
    alphanum = ''
    r = re.findall("[a-zA-Z0-9]",str)
    for i in r:
        alphanum=alphanum+i
    return alphanum

def trimNonA(str):
    alphabet = ''
    r = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]",str)
    for i in r:
        alphabet=alphabet+i
    return alphabet

def findLVM(frame):
    for i in frame:
        if i[2] == 'lvm': 
            LVMindex=frame.index(i)
            partindex=LVMindex-1
            LVMpart=frame[partindex][0]
    return LVMpart

def findLVMsize(frame):
    for i in frame:
        if i[2] == 'lvm': 
            LVMindex=frame.index(i)
            partindex=LVMindex-1
            LVMsize=int(frame[partindex][1])
    return LVMsize

def findAllParts(frame):
    parts=[]
    for i in frame:
        if i[2] == 'part':
            parts.append(trimNonAN(i[0]))
    return parts
    
def removeLVMpart(list, LVMpart):
    noLVMlist=[]
    print("Culling LVM from list.")
    for i in list: 
        print("... " + i + "... ")
        if trimNonA(i) != trimNonA(LVMpart):
            noLVMlist.append(i)
    for j in noLVMlist:
        print("Valid non-LVM partitions: " + j)
    return noLVMlist

def sizeCheck(frame, list, LVMsize):
    validParts=[]
    print("Checking valid partition for size to accomodate the LVM.")
    for i in frame:
        for j in list:
            if i[0] == j:
                print("Valid partition found. Checking size against LVM.")
                if int(i[1]) > LVMsize:
                    validParts.append(i[0])
                    print("Size adequate. " + i[0] + " appended.")
                else:
                    print("Size inadequate.")
#            else:
#                print("Not a valid partition.")
    return validParts

###MAIN SCRIPT###

#Load the file
raw=makeRawFrame(sys.argv[1])
#returns 2D LIST: Make a tidy frame with the drive names, sizes, and types
trim = makeTrimFrame(raw)
print("===============================================================================")
print("trim frame: ")
for i in trim:
    print(i)
print("===============================================================================")
#returns STRING: find the name of the drive/part holding the LVM
rawlvmpart=findLVM(trim)
lvmpart=trimNonAN(rawlvmpart)
print("LVM partition is " + lvmpart)
print("===============================================================================")
#returns INTEGER: find the size of the LVM
size=findLVMsize(trim)
#returns LIST: find the names of all disk partitions
allParts=findAllParts(trim)
#Look for the LVM disk/part in the disk list
#returns LIST: Remove the LVM disk/part from the disk list
onlyParts=removeLVMpart(allParts, lvmpart)
#Look for non-LVM disks in tidy frame and check size against LVM size
#returns LIST
validParts=sizeCheck(trim, onlyParts, size)
if len(validParts) > 0: 
    print("===============================================================================")
    print("Depositing list of valid backup targets.")
#Create a file with the name of the valid disk drive for backup
    outputfile = open(sys.argv[2], "w")
    for i in validParts:
        print("Partition Name: " + i)
        outputfile.write("/dev/" + i +"\n")
    outputfile.close()
    print("Operation complete. .mount2.txt is now updated.")
```

- cron tab is in /etc/cron.d/. I haven't changed its permissions.
  cron tab:

```
# To activate this cron file you have to uncomment the lines below.
# Feel free to adapt it to your needs.
00 11   * * *   root    /usr/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/checkmount.bash >> /usr/local/bin/errorCRON.log 2>&1
54 11   * * *   root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot alpha
# 30 3      * * *       root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot beta
# 0  3      * * 1       root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot gamma
# 30 2      1 * *       root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot delta
```

### Help?

How do I get more information about what is happening with cron while I am logged out? It's not even showing up in /var/log/syslog while I am logged out for an extended period. Should I post the entirety of /var/log/syslog?

### /var/log/cron.log May 14, May 13, May 12 (On May 14, all cron entries are run with me logging in, adjusting the time to 5-10 minutes in the future and logging out; On May 13, I never logged in; on May 12, all cron entries are run with me logging in, adjusting the time to 5-10 minutes in the future and logging out).

```
May 12 16:31:01 clientavnetwork CRON[17459]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/rsnapshot alpha)
May 12 16:33:01 clientavnetwork cron[731]: (*system*mountandsync) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/mountandsync)
May 12 16:39:01 clientavnetwork CRON[17503]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 12 16:41:01 clientavnetwork cron[731]: (*system*mountandsync) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/mountandsync)
May 12 16:42:01 clientavnetwork CRON[17599]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/checkmount.bash >> /usr/local/bin/errorCRON.log 2>&1)
May 12 16:46:01 clientavnetwork cron[731]: (*system*mountandsync) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/mountandsync)
May 12 16:46:01 clientavnetwork CRON[17833]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/checkmount.bash >> /usr/local/bin/errorCRON.log 2>&1)
May 12 16:47:01 clientavnetwork CRON[17862]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/rsnapshot alpha)
May 12 16:50:01 clientavnetwork cron[731]: (*system*mountandsync) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/mountandsync)
May 12 16:53:01 clientavnetwork CRON[18033]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/checkmount.bash >> /usr/local/bin/errorCRON.log 2>&1)
May 12 16:54:01 clientavnetwork CRON[18041]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/rsnapshot alpha)
May 12 21:26:04 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
May 12 21:26:04 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 12 21:26:13 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 12 21:26:13 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 12 21:26:15 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
May 12 21:39:01 clientavnetwork CRON[18332]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 13 06:17:25 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
May 13 06:17:25 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 13 06:17:34 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 13 06:17:34 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 13 06:17:36 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
May 13 06:25:01 clientavnetwork CRON[19759]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
May 13 06:39:01 clientavnetwork CRON[19828]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 13 07:09:01 clientavnetwork CRON[19890]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 13 07:17:01 clientavnetwork CRON[19954]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 13 07:39:01 clientavnetwork CRON[19959]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 13 08:09:01 clientavnetwork CRON[20475]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 13 08:17:01 clientavnetwork CRON[20537]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 13 17:29:11 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
May 13 17:29:12 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 13 17:29:22 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 13 17:29:22 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 13 17:29:24 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
May 13 17:39:01 clientavnetwork CRON[20647]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 13 17:55:27 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
May 13 17:55:29 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 13 17:55:29 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 13 17:55:30 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
May 13 17:55:34 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
May 13 17:55:36 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 13 17:55:36 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 13 17:55:36 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
May 13 17:57:10 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
May 13 18:09:02 clientavnetwork CRON[20718]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 13 18:17:02 clientavnetwork CRON[20780]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 13 18:39:02 clientavnetwork CRON[20784]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 13 20:41:16 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
May 13 20:41:16 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 13 20:41:25 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 13 20:41:25 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 13 20:41:26 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
May 13 21:09:01 clientavnetwork CRON[21354]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 13 21:17:01 clientavnetwork CRON[21417]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 13 21:39:01 clientavnetwork CRON[21421]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 14 07:33:48 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
May 14 07:33:48 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 14 07:33:56 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 14 07:33:56 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 14 07:33:57 clientavnetwork systemd-timesyncd[674]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
May 14 07:39:01 clientavnetwork CRON[22028]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 14 08:09:01 clientavnetwork CRON[23398]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 14 08:17:02 clientavnetwork CRON[23460]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 14 08:39:02 clientavnetwork CRON[23466]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 14 09:09:02 clientavnetwork CRON[23531]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 14 09:17:02 clientavnetwork CRON[23594]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 14 09:39:01 clientavnetwork CRON[23623]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 14 10:09:02 clientavnetwork CRON[23690]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 14 10:17:02 clientavnetwork CRON[23753]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 14 10:39:02 clientavnetwork CRON[23963]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 14 10:47:01 clientavnetwork cron[731]: (*system*mountandsync) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/mountandsync)
May 14 10:53:01 clientavnetwork CRON[24126]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/checkmount.bash >> /usr/local/bin/errorCRON.log 2>&1)
May 14 10:59:01 clientavnetwork cron[731]: (*system*mountandsync) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/mountandsync)
May 14 11:00:01 clientavnetwork CRON[24179]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/checkmount.bash >> /usr/local/bin/errorCRON.log 2>&1)
May 14 11:05:01 clientavnetwork cron[731]: (*system*mountandsync) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/mountandsync)
May 14 11:09:01 clientavnetwork CRON[24324]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 14 11:15:02 clientavnetwork CRON[24392]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/checkmount.bash >> /usr/local/bin/errorCRON.log 2>&1)
May 14 11:17:01 clientavnetwork CRON[24401]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 14 11:38:01 clientavnetwork cron[731]: (*system*mountandsync) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/mountandsync)
May 14 11:39:01 clientavnetwork CRON[25095]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 14 11:42:01 clientavnetwork CRON[25158]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/checkmount.bash >> /usr/local/bin/errorCRON.log 2>&1)
```

Comment: What does `which bash` say?

Comment: Is there no output in /usr/local/bin/errorCRON?

Comment: While debugging, you might set the frequency to run to something like 3 minutes or every 10 minutes, whatever is comfortable for you in debugging.

Comment: As an aside, I would not store output from scripts in `/usr/local/bin`. It is generally reserved for executables. Temp.files can be created in /tmp, and of course root could store files in root's home directory `/root`.

Comment: Also as an aside, aren't you mounting filesystems on top of one another in `/mnt/externaldrive`?

Comment: @Roadowl Yes I would be mounting on top of other drives at /mnt/externaldrive. That is a detail I have to work out later. For the moment, I only have one valid drive that the Python/bash script detects and attempts to mount. If I ever add more drives, I will have a new problem.

Comment: @Roadowl 
"which bash" says: /usr/bin/bash. 
With regard to errorCRON.log, it only outputs stdout IF it runs at all. 
In the instances that I am logged out for a prolonged period, errorCRON.log is not updated, which is confirmed by the timestamp on the file and no new output to the log.

Comment: @Roadowl It may be because my machine is synchronizing with a time sync server every day.  
The times that my CRON runs successfully while I am logged out, I have just editted the file 10-30 minutes before it is scheduled to run. When I review the log, I see that the CRON was reloaded right when I saved the CRON edit. I think the CRON is somehow getting unloaded by another process that runs daily, and thus fails to run on schedule thereafter until I come in and manually reload it again.